# "Продана неизвестная скульптура"?

Tags: стилистика

> "На аукционе ... продана **неизвестная** скульптура Родена."

Нормальное выражение?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, недоработочка. Звучит примерно как *"продать кота в мешке"*.

Скорее всего - неудачный перевод.
Если это был английский, то там, вероятно, стояло fameless. 
Чтобы избежать смешения с unknown по контексту надо переводить ***"неизвестный широкой публике"***, ***"неизвестный специалистам"*** или ***малоизвестный***.

Comment: Похоже, что так.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, здесь такой смысл: На аукционе ... продана **ранее неизвестная** скульптура Родена.

Это означает, что именно на этом аукционе скульптура впервые предъявлена в качестве работы Родена.

Comment: Разве в "ранее неизвестная" можно вложить подобный смысл?! Если продается на аукционе как работа Родена, то она как минимум прошла экспертизу. На момент экспертизы её можно считать "ранее неизвестной" (обычно это означает, что владелец е знал об авторе или же, реже, она вообще была впервые обнвружена в каком-то тайнике) . Но не после экспертизы.

Comment: Не знаю, насчет правильности употребления в этом казуальном контексте, но в жизни точно не так. Скульптура эта действительно продавалась впервые, но авторство было известно с самого начала. Роден подарил её частному лицу, у наследников которого она и хранилась до последнего времени.